# Interop type could not be embedded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, interop

I have a dll from an external vendor; it contains 2 classes:

```
namespace RDTiffDataAccess
{
    public class RDTiffDataClass : IRDTiffData, RDTiffData
    {
        public RDTiffDataClass();
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace RDTiffDataAccess
{
    public interface IRDTiffData
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

I try to call the constructor:

```
RDTiffDataAccess.IRDTiffData Rdt1 = new RDTiffDataAccess.RDTiffDataClass();
```

It gives me an error:

```
Interop type 'RDTiffDataAccess.RDTiffDataClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
```

I have searched and tried a possible solution by changing `Embed Interop Types = false`.

Now it compiles ok, but at run-time, an exception is thrown:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed 
due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

How do I go about resolving this?

Comment: Have you forget to register your COM dlls ?

Comment: I am quite new to this concept. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: U need to register the dlls, compiled with your unmanaged code (if not registered), of which interop dll you are using in your application. To register the dlls use regsvr32.exe located at %WINDIR%/System32 folder

Comment: Unfortunately registering them does not seem to work. On a side note, the dlls are working fine in another c# example that was already provided, so I do not think it should be an issue of registration.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but could help someone else. 
Try to change the project properties to x86 platform target on Build section.
Maybe the dlls were built targeting 86 bits.